# How can I resolve this loop that asks to duplicate input?

Tags: python

I'm still struggling with Python but it's been a good time. I keep running into this problem and unsure of how to get past it. The issue is that when I run the program, every time I make an input for the game it prompts me with another input asking if I want to play again. When I input yes, it goes forward with the program but after every line after it keeps asking me if I want to play again while I'm already in the process of playing the game. Is there something I've missed because when I compare it to the original code I have it matched in the same way as far as I'm aware. If someone has seen something I've missed or have run into the error before please let me know. Thank you!

````
import random

def drawBoard(board):
    # This function prints out the board that it was passed

    # "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')

def inputPlayerLetter():
    # Lets the player type which letter they want to be.
    # Returns a list with the player's letter as the first item, and the computer's letter as the second
    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be X or O?')
        letter = input().upper()

    # the first element in the list is the player's letter, the second is the compiuter's letter.
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

def whoGoesFirst():
    # Randomly choose the player who goes first.
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'computer'
    else:
        return 'player'

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def makeMove (board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter

def isWinner(bo, le):
    # Given a board and the player's letter, this function returns True if that player has won.
    # We use bo instead of board and le instead of letter so we don't have to type as much.
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or # across the top
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or # across the middle
    (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or # across the bottom
    (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or # down the left side
    (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or # down the middle
    (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or # down the right side
    (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or # diagonal
    (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) # diagonal

def getBoardCopy(board):
            # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
            dupeBoard = []

            for i in board:
                dupeBoard.append(i)

            return dupeBoard

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
            # Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
            return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
            # Let the player type in their move.
            move = ' '
            while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
                print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
                move = input()
            return int(move)

def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, movesList):
            # Returns a valid move from the passed list on the passed board.
            #Returns None if there is no valid move.
            possibleMoves = []
            for i in movesList:
                if isSpaceFree(board, i):
                    possibleMoves.append(i)

            if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
                return random.choice(possibleMoves)
            else:
                return None

def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
            # Given a board and the computer's letter, determine where to move and return that move.
            if computerLetter == 'X':
                playerLetter = 'O'
            else:
                playerLetter = 'X'

            # Here is our algorithm for the Tic Tac Toe AI:
            # First, check if we can win in the next move
            for i in range(1, 10):
                copy = getBoardCopy (board)
                if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
                    makeMove(copy, computerLetter, i)
                    if isWinner(copy, computerLetter):
                        return i

            # Check if the player could win on their next move, and block them.
            for i in range(1, 10):
                copy = getBoardCopy(board)
                if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
                    makeMove(copy, playerLetter, i)
                    if isWinner(copy, playerLetter):
                        return i

            # Try to take one of the corners, if they are free.
            move = chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
            if move != None:
                return move

            # Try to take the center, if it is free.
            if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
                return 5

            # Move on one of the sides.
            return chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [2, 4, 6, 8])

def isBoardFull(board):
    # Return True if every space on the board has been taken. Otherwise return False.
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            return False
    return True


print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

while True:
    # Reset the board
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
    gameIsPlaying = True

    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'player':
            # Player's turn.
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'

        else:
            # Computer's turn.
            move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
            makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
                gameisPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player'

        if not playAgain():
                break```
````

Comment: Your playAgain condition is incomplete, it should be: if (not gameisPlaying and not playAgain()):

Comment: Does that tutorial really suggest function names like `whoGoesFirst`? According to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it should be all lowercase with underscores: `who_goes_first`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the second while loop.

```
while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'player':
            # Player's turn.
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'

        else:
            # Computer's turn.
            move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
            makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
                gameisPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player'

        if not playAgain():
                break
```

The loop will first call the first if statement `if turn == 'player':`. If this is false then the `else` statment will be run. Then `if not playAgain()` will be run. This will happen for every iteration of the loop.

Changing the indentation so that the final if statement is not included in the `while gameIsPlaying` loop should fix the problem.